# Displaying ngModel value for mat-select

Tags: angular, select, angular-material, angular-ngmodel

I am using Angular Material Select to display holidays. When the user selects a holiday, I would like to display the date instead of the holiday name. For example, if the user selects "Christmas", I want the selected value to should show "December 25"

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedHoliday" placeholder="Select A Holiday" (change)="eventSelection($event.value)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let holiday of holidays" [value]="holiday">{{ holiday.name }}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

I set ngmodel to the correct date on select change:

```
selectedHoliday: string;

holidays = [
 { name: 'Christmas', date: 'Dec 25'} ,
 { name: 'New Years', date: 'Jan 1'}
]


eventSelection(event){
 this.selectedHoliday = event.date
}
```

When I set selectedHoliday to the date, nothing displays as the selected value. Here is a plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/9lhHJhNyuWUxqYF6nMwK?p=preview

Answer (score 17):

The options `value` is set to the `holiday` object and `[(ngModel)]` is set to the `date` property of the selected event, in your case `holiday.date`.

So the `select` looks for the option with value `holiday.date` but your options have value `holiday`.

The `select` `[(ngModel)]` has to correlate to the `value` of its `option`.

```
[value]="holiday.date"
```

[Updated Plunker fork](https://plnkr.co/edit/cozg6FkfDzJs0NwSf8pu?p=preview)