# Angular display data in select

Tags: angular, select, angular7

I'm using angular 7 and I want when I click in update User I get a page with all info about that user so I can update what I want, but on validator attribute I don't see the value of it from database.

This is my code:

```
<div fxFlex="50" class="pr-1">
        <mat-form-field class="full-width">
          <mat-select placeholder="Validator *" name="validator" [formControl]="indicateurForm.controls['validator']" class="mb-1">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let v of listValidators" [value]="v" ngDefaultControl>
              {{v?.firstName}} {{v?.lastName}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
```

if I use 'input' I got the result of the validator but on 'select' I got nothing display.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What i see is {{v?.firstName}} {{v?.lastName}} means that v is object, I think you can't parse [value]="v" into selectBox value.

Comment: @shadowman_93 yeah I want display firstName and lastName and I want stock the whole object in database

Answer (score 1):

As I undestand you can't parse `[value]="v"` into selectBox value,

```
      <div fxFlex="50" class="pr-1">
        <mat-form-field class="full-width">
          <mat-select placeholder="Validator *" name="validator" [formControl]="indicateurForm.controls['validator']" class="mb-1">
            //Try to parse value like id here, example [value]="v.id" 
            <mat-option *ngFor="let v of listValidators" [value]="v" ngDefaultControl> 
              {{v?.firstName}} {{v?.lastName}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
```

**Update:** I found this, Its exactly what you need. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35945293/5955138

It's telling that you need to use `[ngValue]` property like below,

```
<h1>My Application</h1>
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
  <option *ngFor="let c of countries" [ngValue]="c">{{c.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I can't use [ngValue] cuz I don't use ngModel, I use [formControl], and I can't do [value]="v.id" coz If I do that the id who will display. so I think is impossible to display 2 attributes of an object and stock the all oubject :(

Comment: @RagnarLodbrok It seems like in this example, they used ngValue with mat-select, Can you please check it, https://stackoverflow.com/a/48197226/5955138

Comment: I got this error : Can't bind to 'ngValue' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-option'.
I have already import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; but still same error; I must import just 1 but also not working