# add custom validation in input type text using angular material stepper

Tags: javascript, angular, validation, angular-material, angular-material-stepper

I am using angular stepper to display all my data and take input for some of the text boxes, but I want to add my custom validations when user clicks on `Next` button.

[stackblitz - material-stepper-custom-validation](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-stepper-custom-validation)

**html:**

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper>
  <mat-step>
    <div class="m-10">
      <input type="text" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" >
      </div>
      <div class="m-10">
      <input type="text" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name" >
      </div>
      <div>
        <button mat-button (click)="checkData()" matStepperNext>Next</button>
      </div>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="secondFormGroup" [optional]="isOptional">
        <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
        <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>      
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step>
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Done</ng-template>
    You are now done.
    <div>
      <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
      <button mat-button (click)="stepper.reset()">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

Here, first name and last name should be validated before go to next stepper, but not using formGroup.

**ts:**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'stepper-optional-example',
  templateUrl: 'stepper-optional-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['stepper-optional-example.css']
})
export class StepperOptionalExample implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() { }

  checkData() {    
    let lname = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("fname")).value;
    if(lname == '') {
      alert('error');
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

**How?** - If first name is empty then don't allow them to go `Next` stepper.

Comment: I recommend you have a look at [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms). Also this `(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("fname")).value` is 100% not done when using Angular.

Comment: Is that possible without reactive forms?

Comment: @GiovaniVercauteren Also I have some typical view when uses enters information.

Comment: @PathikVejani You should be able to do this with template driven forms as well, but the code wouldn't be as clean. You should be able to prevent going onto the next steps by using the [completed] and [editable] directives by adding them to the corresponding mat-step elements.

Comment: @saglamcem any example would be appreciated.

Comment: @PathikVejani can i know any specific reason for not using formGroup, Drawbacks or disadvantages of formGroup

Comment: @PathikVejani I'll try to provide a stackblitz in a couple of hours - but the essence would be that you keep an object in the ts file like user: {fname: string, lname: string}, bind those values to the template using [(ngModel)] (like [(ngModel)]="user.fname"), and when checkData() is called, just check the user object with your necessary validations :)

Comment: @mayur I am loading components dynamic in stepper and I don't know how to handle those in click of save button. Also, there are drop-down, checkboxex etc..

Comment: Reactive approach has much more options and can handle dynamic data and dynamic form elements in a breeze, but it needs some minor preparation to setup, but in the end you can do much more with Reactive forms, but if you just use a smaller setup then I recomment using the template driven approach like I posted below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you use the template driven approach, you will need to map all input fields into an ngModel somehow. Here is an example for it:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" required [(ngModel)]="model.name" name="name">
```

TS:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'stepper-optional-example',
  templateUrl: 'stepper-optional-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['stepper-optional-example.css']
})
export class StepperOptionalExample implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('stepper') stepper;

  model = {
    name: 'Initial Value'
  }

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() { }

}
```

Using that you can then, check the attribute onClick. You need to remove the `matStepperNext` and add the `(click)` event listener instead like so:

HTML:

```
<button mat-button (click)="onNext()">Next</button>
```

TS:

```
onNext() {
  // Validate your value in the function
  if (this.model.name !== 'Henry') {
    this.stepper.next();
  }
}
```

Other than that I also recommend to take a look on the official guide showing how to implement the template driven approach: https://angular.io/guide/forms

Comment: I am not understating how to do for drop-down.

Comment: @PathikVejani pretty much the same logic. You keep a value in the ts file for the selected dropdown value, and assign [(ngModel)] to the <select>. You should be able to find a lot of answers for this on StackOverflow, as it is a very common question.

Comment: @saglamcem yes, got it. Thanks

Comment: getting this: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

Comment: Here is the documentation for the `select` that you might need: https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview and here you can see how to implement it with the template driven approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48170526/displaying-ngmodel-value-for-mat-select

Comment: What I did is: `<input type="text" placeholder="name" required (ngModel)="model?.name" name="name">`, in ts: `model: {
    name: '' }`, but when I check for validation on click of button: `if(this.model.name == '') {
    } else {
      stepper.next();
    }` it gives me an error. error: `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

Comment: Your `model` is undefined.

Comment: like: `model: { name: '' }`

Comment: It must be `model = { name: '' }`

Comment: @LingVu oh.. it's `=`. I type `:`

Comment: @LingVu how to get entered values on click of `next` button? I want to console all added values

Comment: I miss the context. What do you mean? Add it to the question please.